# Navigate between react tabs on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-tabs

I am new to React. I am using [React web tabs](https://github.com/marcuslindfeldt/react-web-tabs/) to create tabs in react.

How would one go about triggering a change of tab panels upon clicking a button element, I have two button, "Previous" & "Next". On click of previous button , i want to go to previous tab & On next button click it should show next tab ?

```
 <Tabs defaultTab="one"  vertical className="vertical-tabs" selectedIndex={this.state.selectedTabIndex} 
            onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
            <TabList>
              <Tab tabFor="one"  >BASIC INFORMATION</Tab>
              <Tab tabFor="two"  >ADVANCED INFORMATION</Tab>
              <Tab tabFor="three">ASSIGN USERS</Tab>
              <Tab tabFor="four" >TEMPLATE</Tab>
            </TabList>
            <TabPanel tabId="one">
            //BASIC INFORMATION
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel tabId="two">
            //ADVANCED INFORMATION
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel tabId="three">
            //ASSIGN USERS
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel tabId="four">
            //TEMPLATE
            </TabPanel>
             {
              <div>
    <Button onClick={()=>this.handlePreviousBtnChange()}>Back</Button> 
  </div>}{<div>
 <Button onClick={()=>this.handleNextBtnChange()}>Next</Button> 
</div>}                                 
</Tabs>
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, sorry, the query com can make const tabCount = 3 not a fixed amount but infinite, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this closed issue on the project, you should be able to use defaultTab to programmatically change the selected tab. https://github.com/marcuslindfeldt/react-web-tabs/issues/10#issuecomment-482846520

Here's a short example. I made the tab ids numbers to make incrementing/decrementing easier.

```js
const ControllableTabs = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);
  const tabCount = 3;

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs defaultTab={selectedTab.toString()}>
        <TabList>
          <Tab tabFor="0">Tab 1</Tab>
          <Tab tabFor="1">Tab 2</Tab>
          <Tab tabFor="2">Tab 3</Tab>
        </TabList>
        <TabPanel tabId="0">
          <p>Tab 1 content</p>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel tabId="1">
          <p>Tab 2 content</p>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel tabId="2">
          <p>Tab 3 content</p>
        </TabPanel>
      </Tabs>
      <Button onClick={() => setSelectedTab((selectedTab + tabCount - 1) % tabCount )}>Back</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => setSelectedTab((selectedTab + 1) % tabCount )}>Next</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I should note that there are other libraries that possibly suit your needs better, depending on the functionality that you desire. If you happen to be using material-ui in your project already, the Stepper component provides much more customizability. https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#stepper

Comment: Hello, sorry, the query com can make const tabCount = 3 not a fixed amount but infinite, thanks